# Ubuntu 13.10 : No Module Named appindicator

Tags: python, ubuntu, appindicator

Appindicator is not available on Ubuntu 13.10?

```
jason@jz:~$ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import appindicator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named appindicator
>>>
```

Is there an alternative of it? Or can I install it myself?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install python-appindicator
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably should aim for Python 3 instead:

`sudo apt-get install gir1.2-appindicator`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install it yourself. I'd recommend looking at [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) for installing additional python packages.